# Name and Proof of a Matrix Inequality

Tags: matrices

Is this inequality has any special name ? Where can i find a proof of it ?

$\| (X+Y)^n - X^n \|\le(\|X\|+\|Y\|)^n - \|X\|^n$ for each $n$.

I'm actually looking for proof for the different "right side" inequality
which is

$\| (X+Y)^n - X^n \|$ ≤||B|| ||A|| ^(n-1)  e^(||B||/||A||)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$(X+Y)^n-X^n$ is equal to the sum of homogeneous terms of the form $X^{x_1}Y^{y_1}X^{x_2}\cdots Y^{y_k}$. By the inequality $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|$ for all matrices $A,B$ we have that $\|X^{x_1}\cdots Y^{y_k}\|\leq\|X\|^{\sum x_i}\|Y\|^{\sum y_i}$. If we sum these terms and concentrate a little, the result is exactly $(\|X\|+\|Y\|)^n-\|X\|^n$. I do not know if there is a name to this inequality.